# Adding component to App JS file not working

Tags: reactjs

I just created a js file component but when I import this to App js file it gives me error. Am I importing wrong the component file?

I tried to re-create the file but it's not working.

This is my App js file:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

//Component
import City from './components/City';

class App extends Component {

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          //Adding component
          <City />
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
          Learn REACT
          </a>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is my component js file:

```
class City extends Component {

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Hola componente</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default City;
```

This is my dependencies in package.json

````
{
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  }
}```



console shows this error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token !

!(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module 'react'"); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }());
var _jsxFileName = "D:\\react\\practica\\src\\components\\City.js";


class City extends !(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module 'react'"); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }())
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to import react into your component files

`import React, { Component } from 'react'`

Comment: Yes, I have that in my file component and I added it to my post but I don't why it's not showing up :(

Comment: Have you run `npm install`

Comment: It works, I deleted package-lock.json and run npm install. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to import react and component!

`import React, {Component} from 'react';`